# Secure automated test for live shopping cart checkout with credit card using Selenium

Tags: security, magento, selenium, credit-card, nightwatch.js

I'd like to test a live shopping cart (Magento) with real credit card data and to a checkout to ensure checkout works after a code release.

How do I store the credit card data to use in selenium on the live site?

I'm using Nightwatch.js testing framework which runs on Node.js. The test is written in Javascript and can access any HTTP endpoint, TCP or file or do anything Node.js can do.

Ideally I'd like to either encrypt the credit card data and store it either locally via a service. Then request this data during checkout and just enter the ccv in the command line during the test.

Optionally I'd like to enter the credit card data at the beginning of the test and secure store this temporarily in memory until all tests are run.

I'd like this to comply with PCI standards.

Notes:

The tests run in a Node.js process that controls a Selenium Server via Nightwatch.js API. The Selenium server is on a local TCP socket and sends commands to the browser process via the Selenium Webdriver API.

Comment: Where is the Selenium server? Is this your local laptop or a remote system?

Comment: Selenium server is on the same machine running the tests.

Comment: Which is where? In your office or in the "cloud"? Where is the Node.js process and where will you enter your card details for the test?

Comment: Essentially whichever server it is will need to have the same controls for protecting card data as any other under PCI DSS. Both while in transit and at rest in memory.

Comment: Selenium server and tests are on local machine. Site to be tested is on public internet accessed via HTTPS.

Comment: Is there a specific encryption require to ensure PCI DSS?

Comment: Yes, it's complicated. To quote PCI DSS do's and don'ts: Encryption keys used for encryption of cardholder data must be protected against both disclosure and misuse. All key management processes and procedures for keys used for encryption of cardholder data must be fully documented and implemented. For more details, see PCI DSS Requirement 3.

Comment: Ok I guess my question would be answered by answering "How to encrypt CC data to PCI DSS standards". :)

Comment: Not quite because you don't want your local machine becoming within PCI scope. They basically say don't test with real card numbers.

Comment: Have a look at 6.4.3 in [PCI DSS 3.1](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-1.pdf) `6.4.3 Production data (live PANs) are not used for testing or development`.

Comment: I'd assume using a non customer credit card would not fall under "Production data"? Like a company card with limited funds.